# Does the Spectre have powers to create things?

Tags: dc

Sort of related to this question:
[Why doesn't the Spectre beat everything?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123686/why-doesnt-the-spectre-beat-everything?r=SearchResults)

Does the Spectre have powers to create things like change his surroundings around him like for example change a volcano into a swamp removing the whole mountain with his mind, making Kryptonite shine out of his cloak to debilitate Superman, create quicksand from nothing to sink hero's who aren't prepared for it?

These are the things I think the Spectre can do, but what exactly can the Spectre actually do?

Comment: I wrote I think it might be related just to emphasize the question of what can the spectre exactly do?

Comment: The Spectre is pretty darn powerful. I can't believe that an entity above Galactus on the food chain isn't able to perform relatively minor reality warping.